# Why doesn't this JavaScript fade-in function work

Tags: javascript

```
    fadeIn = function(r, s) {
        var self = this, t;
        if (!self instanceof Element) return false;
        t = setInterval(function() {
            self.style.opacity = (self.style.opacity) + s;
            if (self.style.opacity == ".90") {
                clearInterval(t);
            }
        }, r);
    }
box = document.getElementById("box");
fadeIn.apply(box, [30, .2]);
```

I know I would be better off using JQuery but I am just experimenting. When I click 'box' the opacity is sharply taken down but to 0.1 but it's not a fade like how I would have liked it to be.

Comment: What is a delay and how do I use it??

Comment: on this line: `self.style.opacity = (self.style.opacity) + s;` you're adding a list, `[30,.2]`, to a number. According to your interval, `r` is supposed to be a number, but it's a `box` ... box = document.getElementById("box"); ... so you're function isn't getting what it expects as inputs

Comment: @Stephen I am using the apply method so I am giving the values of the arguments within the array []. So technically it is valid.

Comment: Oh I never use the apply method so I made a faulty assumption about what it does.

Comment: try putting the last 2 lines in a function to be executed on `body.onload`

Comment: Don't use setInterval at all. Rather, take a look at the JavaScript Animation API. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/animation

Comment: Or just use css transition with or without the use of classes. It seems to me this is exactly what you want. You want to transition some css attribute(s) over time.